# How to search a field with a JSON value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL column containing fields with data looking like this:

```
["I don't read books anymore","books \/ novels"]
```

I would like to retrieve all fields with 'books / novels'. How can I do so? I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where data_field like '%books \/ novels%'
```

but that returns zero results. Why? How are JSON fields supposed to be searched?

Comment: As of Mysql 5.7 there is now JSON column types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date_field like '%books \\\\/ novels%'
```

See note here: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, `\n` to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any `\` that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for `\n`, specify it as `\\n`.
>   To search for `\`, specify it as `\\\\`; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

As you pointed out, the below doesn't work because it can possibly match other strings:

You could try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where data_field like '%books __ novels%'
```

or possibly this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` where data_field like '%books _ novels%'
```

The underscore is a single character wild card in like searches.

Comment: that won't work... Because then books / novels and books + novels become the same thing.